# addFileAttachmentAsync() is not functioning as expected on Outlook Desktop on Windows 10 machine

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to add inline image to mail body through Outlook Add-in. It works fine in OWA but Desktop app fails to attach it inline, instead I get the image as a regular attachment, and broken image icon on email body.

I contacted Microsoft Devchat, they don't seem to able to repro it, I tried the code they sent me , and it behaves the same.

Here is the code:

```
function AttCallback(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.log(asyncResult.error);
    } else {
        var szCID = asyncResult.asyncContext.UniqueName;
        var szAddBodyData = "<p>Here's a cute bird!</p><br><div><img src='cid:" + szCID + "'></div><br>";
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
            szAddBodyData,
            { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html });
        console.log("Attachment added");
    }
}
function insertAttachment() {
    var szName = "cute_bird.png";
    var options = { isInline: true, ContentId: szName, 'asyncContext': { UniqueName: szName } };
    //var options = { asyncContext: null };
    Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
        "http://i.imgur.com/WJXklif.png",
        szName,
        options,
        AttCallback);
}
```

Here is what is happening on my machine.
Note: As you can see from the code, by the time callback function gets hit, attachment was already added. However I do have inline property set to true.
[image]

Has anyone experienced it before? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried the code on the latest Outlook Desktop Win32 and it works. Older versions of Desktop Outlook did NOT support this feature. If you are on a 16.0.4XXX.1000 version of Outlook (the MSI builds), only support API Set 1.4. And this feature requires API Set 1.5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/outlook-requirement-set-1.5

Comment: That must be it. My Outlook Dekstop version is 16.0.4738.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - is there documentation which maps the build numbers to req. sets?

Comment: For your addin, instead of checking build version, it's preferable to use Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('Mailbox', 1.5) to check if the API is supported.  Or alternatively, if you simply do not want your addin to appear in older clients, you can set the requirement set in the manifest as you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

See from the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/outlook-requirement-set-1.5

that inline image addition support shipped with Outlook requirement set `1.5`. You should specify this capability in your `manifest.xml` to ensure your add-in is only appearing in clients where it can work and not show up if it can't.

Comment: I don't think we can have conditional statements on manifest. We had similar issue with some API calls that were not supported on Outlook 2013 but were fine on 2016, we couldn't hide the feature when 2013 was detected. In fact it was a action command on Outlook desktop. On add-in click we were offering a dropdown of choices and we had to hide one for 2013because it was not supported. we ended up just including "not supported " message when item is clicked

Comment: Right, the manifest will control whether the addin appears or not, but you cannot have buttons be hidden per requirement set.  At runtime, your addin can check whether the API requirement set is supported using Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('Mailbox', 1.5).